# Which methods destroy/unset session(s) variable(s) and work efficiently in most PHP version as well?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to unset **and** destroy a specific session and I came across different methods and would like to know which is the efficient method to do the work and deals with most php versions as well.

First method:

```
unset($_SESSION['site1']);
session_destroy();
```

Second method:

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

**Update: [RESOLVED]**

```
<?php
session_start();

unset($_SESSION['site1']);
?>
```

Comment: `session_unset` and `session_destroy` don't accept any parameters.

Comment: `session_unset` and `session_destroy` don't take parameters...they are for unsetting all session variables, or destroying the session...

Comment: It's a difficult choice, considering that both options trigger warnings :)

Comment: So `unset($_SESSION['site1']);` is the way to go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `unset` to unset any array index. And Session itself is an array. So use `unset` to unset your particular session index. You are wrong in the case of `session_unset` and `session_destroy` functions as they don't accept any parameters.

Also the point to note is that, you should not be using `session_destroy` as it will unset all available sessions. For eg. while loggin out, you may not be wanting to lose your products in cart formed using session.

**Edit**

`session_destroy — Destroys all data registered to a session`

`session_unset — Frees all session variables`

session_unset just clears the $_SESSION variable. It’s equivalent to doing:

`$_SESSION = array();`
So this does only affect the local $_SESSION variable instance but not the session data in the session storage.

In contrast to that, session_destroy destroys the session data that is stored in the session storage (e.g. the session file in the file system).

Everything else remains unchanged.

Comment: So `unset($_SESSION['site1']);` is the way to go?

Comment: Yeah, thats the right way to do it, if u don't want to risk losing any other session data by accident other than the unwanted one.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer.

Comment: So in the beginning of the page I want to unset the session I will use it. Can you check my question, I added the resolved statements, and see if it's correctly used. Thanks again.

Comment: Yea the resolved portion is absolutely correct. And one more suggestion to you, if you remove the parameters for `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()`, you will not receive further negative votes. Eg.  `session_unset();`
`session_destroy();`

Answer (score 3):

`session_unset` does not take any parameters. It frees ALL session variables.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've called `session_start()`, you should treat `$_SESSION` just like any other object.

Because of that, `unset` will do just fine.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the feedback.